# Remove any blank spaces of NAs

Tags: r, string, subset, na

I have a vector which contains numbers, NAs and blanks where I only wish to keep the numbers. I was initially trying a *gsub* out everything that wasnt a number using;

```
gsub(!'[:digit:]', '', myexample)
```

Although had no joy. Thinking more I'm not sure a *gsub* is the best think to use here, maybe a *which()* argument although I'm not sure how you'd only select digits.

Example of vector shown below;

```
myexample
# [1]   "319939" ""       ""       "318273" NA       "317889" NA       "316060"
```

Part two of my question is when we are dealing with characters rather than numbers. In this instance I wish to do the same (keep the names), and remove the nas (na-na) and black values ("-"). Although this time as this vector comes from a paste R does not recognize na-na as a true NA value.

```
characterexample
"random-name"      "-"                 "-"   "na-na"              "name-random"
```

Comment: Maybe using `na.omit(as.numeric(myexample))` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could use `grep` instead of `gsub`

```
> myexmaple <- c("319939", "", "", "318273", NA, "317889", NA, "316060")

> grep("^\\d+$", myexmaple, value = TRUE)
[1] "319939" "318273" "317889" "316060"
```

---

For you second question, you can use `%in%`

```
> characterexample[!characterexample %in% c("na-na", "-")]
[1] "random-name" "name-random"
```

Comment: Super stuff, is there any way this can be done using characters aswell? I've updated the question with an example

Comment: @Joe what is your expected output for `characterexample`?

Comment: Yep sorry should have said. Looking to remove anything thats "-"  or "na-na", but as the nas here com from a paste I dont think R recognizes them as NA values. I've tried searching for '[characters]-[characters] but the na-na will still get included in that

Comment: @Joe Please make more clarifications in your question such others can see it with details.

Comment: Sure, will update